# How to pass numbers as arrays - Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass an array of numbers in a multipart to my api. In my api, i check if the numbers are in array form and validate. However, i send my phone numbers in array form but then my api doesn't validate it as an array.

What am i doing wrong in sending my numbers as array

```
 $request = $client->post($target_url, [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'file',
                    'contents' => 'info',
                ],

                [
                    'name' => 'phone',
                    'contents' => [
                        0 => '+44234234292',
                        1 => '+0234823421'
                    ])
                ],

];
```

Comment: You have the end parenthesis at the wrong location... `'contents' => [
                        0 => '+44234234292',
                        1 => '+0234823421'
                    ]`**)**

Comment: Thanks for that..but that isn't the solution

Comment: Have you tried removing `)`? and its posted in comment as suggestion not as a solution.

Comment: @AdityaThakur, yes i have and the error still remains as `Invalid resource type: array`

Comment: try passing the array as json data, 'json' : [0 => '+44234234292', 1 => '+0234823421']

Answer (score 0):

As per guzzle docs, `'content'` cannot contain arrays, you can pass the array as a `json_encoded` data or you can send it as

```
'json' => [0 => '+44234234292',  1 => '+0234823421']
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `]`.

Comment: My bad, Thank you